# Line graph not working as expected: angular 7

Tags: angular, chart.js

I've an API from where I'm fetching data.

> url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1dnpid';

**`HTML Code:`**

```js
<div *ngIf="chart" class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6">
  <div class="card cardColor mb-3">
    <div class="card-header headColor">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="../../../assets/images/chart-bars-box-16-white.png" /> &nbsp;
      <b>Issue Chart</b>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <canvas id="canvas">{{ chart }}</canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**`Angular code (XHR request):`**

```js
// line graph
this.httpClient.get(this.url).subscribe((res: Data[]) => {
  Array.isArray(res);
  console.log(res);

  // this.result.forEach(y => {
  // this.year.push(y.year);
  // this.price.push(y.price);
  // });


  Array.from(res).forEach(function (y: Data) {
    this.year.push(y.year);
    this.price.push(y.price);
  });
  this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: this.year,
      datasets: [
        {
          data: this.price,
          borderColor: '#0076CE',
          fill: false
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      legend: {
        display: true
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          display: true
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          display: true
        }]
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I've an interface:
**`data.ts:`**

```js
export interface Data {
  year: String;
  price: number;
}
```

But the graph is empty as shown.
[image: Line Graph]
But I get data in console:

> results: Array(5)
>       0: {year: "2015", price: "978"}
>       1: {year: "2016", price: "657"}
>       2: {year: "2017", price: "989"}
>       3: {year: "2018", price: "1045"}
>       4: {year: "2019", price: "300"}
>       length: 5

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(res);` in subscribe ? Shouldn't it be `res.results` as per the json.

Comment: `res` is an object where as `res.results` is the array you are looking for

Comment: I think it is because you are using an array of strings , I suggest you convert the string to be int or number, that might work

Comment: @Niladri: Output of `console.log(res);` is `results: Array(5)
0: {year: "2015", price: "978"}
1: {year: "2016", price: "657"}
2: {year: "2017", price: "989"}
3: {year: "2018", price: "1045"}
4: {year: "2019", price: "300"}
length: 5`

Comment: @AmericoArvani: How would you convert `Array.from(res)` into `int`?

Comment: @AjayKulkarni Can you print the values of `this.year` and `this.price` after the `forEach`

Comment: @AjayKulkarni  just do parseInt(y.price)

Comment: @AjayKulkarni also you need to change to fetch the root collection which is Array.from(res.results)

Comment: You might want to consider using [ng2-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-charts) which is a wrapper library around chart.js